# How do I add/remove attributes and methods?

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to develop a system where a user should be able to make modifications [add/remove attributes and methods] in the actual java file. While there are methods provided by API to create new methods/fields, how can we remove/destroy the ones that are not required.

I want to make a method

```
updatefile(file, newMethods, newAttributes)
```

- `file` is the java file that is going to be modified whose methods and attributes need to be removed.
- `newMethods` would now be methods of file
- `newAttributes` would be attributes of file

It is also possible that some entries of newMethods == some entries of original methods for which I will require a check; similarly for newAttributes.

How can this be done?

Comment: Adding methods and attributes to a Java class is called programming. Give them Eclipse, NetBeans or IntelliJ: they're all good IDEs, and will all be better than your application to add attributes and methods to Java source files.

Answer (score 1):

You need a bytecode manipulation library. Check the following: bcel, cglib, asm, javassist.

Though I agree with JBNizet that the requirements look a bit strange. There are already powerful IDEs that do that, and end users shouldn't normally temper with the class structure.

Comment: thanx... will c n then get back

Comment: actually i m trying to develop a tool to automate development. there are certain sets of standard classes that r available, each new class that will b introduced into the system will be some sort of modification of that standard class. therefore, i would like to provide an interface to select newMethods and newAttributes from amongst the standards. of course if i have to add some method/attribute that does not exist even in standard, i will have to code it manually.

Comment: Then you just need to provide a good, reusable, well-documented OO library of classes and methods. OO design, inheritance, composition, and design patterns are your best friends. This is still programming, and an IDE is still the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea seem's similar to the JBoss forge project.

I think a possibility to remove methods must be based on Java method's signature declared in Java specs and a method return type.

For example: methodRemove(File file, String returnType, String methodName, String[] methodParametersTypes) will reference appropriate method to remove in file in case of only one class in file.

Comment: and methodAttributes contains attributes types.

Comment: Your thanx can be more helpful using up arrow at my answer :)